# Compute the Fourier Series for $f(x)=\cos(\frac{x}{2})$ for the domain $(-\pi<x≤\pi)$ and $f(x)=f(x+2\pi)$

Tags: fourier-series

I know that $b_{n}$ is an even function, due to the function being an even function, however I am struggling to compute $a_{n}$.

Comment: What is $a_n$ and $b_n$?

Comment: the Fourier Coefficients of  $f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(a_n \cos(\frac{2\pi}{T}nx) + b_n \sin(\frac{2\pi}{T}nx)\right)$

Comment: That should be $f(x)=f(x+2\pi)$ I should think. f(x) is even so it has no odd components. What do you know about the sin/cos in terms of odd/even?

Answer (score 0):

1. $$a_0=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(\frac{x}{2})dx$$
   $$=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(\frac{x}{2})d(\frac{x}{2})$$
   $$=\frac{2}{\pi} \left[\sin(\frac{x}{2})\right]_{-\pi}^{\pi}$$
   $$=\frac{4}{\pi}$$
2. $$a_n=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(\frac{x}{2})\cdot \cos nx dx$$
   $$=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}2\cos(\frac{x}{2})\cdot \cos nx dx$$
   $$=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left[\cos\frac{(2n+1)x}{2} + \cos\frac{(2n-1)x}{2} \right] dx$$
   $$=\frac{1}{2\pi} \cdot \frac{2}{2n+1} \left[\sin\frac{(2n+1)x}{2} + \sin\frac{(2n-1)x}{2} \right]_{-\pi}^{\pi}$$
   $$=\frac{1}{\pi} \cdot \frac{1}{2n+1} \left[2\sin\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2} + 2\sin\frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2} \right]$$

I think you can complete the last line and that $b_n=0$ since $f(x)$ is even.

Comment: Are you sure you're using an orthonormal basis? Is this the $L_2[-\pi,\pi]$ inner product?

Comment: @Ranc Is anything wrong with my procedure? You are welcome to point them out.

Comment: If the basis is ${ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}, \dfrac{\cos(nx)}{\sqrt{\pi}}, \dfrac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{\pi}} }_{n\in\mathbb N}$ (An orthonormal basis) Then you get different coefficients then what you got.

Comment: @Ranc I admit that I don't have any idea of these things like basis and inner product that you are talking about. I have learnt fourier series in my classes and it did not involve those topics. Perhaps it will be a part of a latter course of mine. I used the simple preliminary formula and procedure to derive the results. I think you should post an answer of yours involving your ideas. And if you notice any other basic flaws in my working, you are welcome to sort them out. I'll surely co-operate to the best of my knowledge.